# How to achieve Asynchrony instead of Parallelism in F#

Tags: performance, f#, asynchronous, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

(Sticking to a common example with async fetch of many web pages)

How would I spin off multiple (hundreds) of web page requests asynchronously, and then wait for all requests to complete before going to the next step?  Async.AsParallel processes a few requests at a time, controlled by number of cores on the CPU.  Grabbing a web page is not a CPU-bound operation.  Not satisfied with the speedup of Async.AsParallel, I am looking for alternatives.

I tried to connect the dots between Async.StartAsTask and Task[].WaitAll.  Instinctively, I wrote the following code, but it does not compile.

```
let processItemsConcurrently (items : int seq) = 
  let tasks = items |> Seq.map (fun item -> Async.StartAsTask(fetchAsync item))
  Tasks.Task.WaitAll(tasks)
```

How would you approach this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Async.Parallel` is almost definitely right here.  Not sure what you're not happy with; the strength of F# asyncs lies more in async computing than in task-parallel CPU-bound stuff (which is more tailored to `Task`s and the .NET 4.0 TPL).  Here's a full example:

```
open System.Diagnostics 
open System.IO
open System.Net
open Microsoft.FSharp.Control.WebExtensions 

let sites = [|
    "http://bing.com"
    "http://google.com"
    "http://cnn.com"
    "http://stackoverflow.com"
    "http://yahoo.com"
    "http://msdn.com"
    "http://microsoft.com"
    "http://apple.com"
    "http://nfl.com"
    "http://amazon.com"
    "http://ebay.com"
    "http://expedia.com"
    "http://twitter.com"
    "http://reddit.com"
    "http://hulu.com"
    "http://youtube.com"
    "http://wikipedia.org"
    "http://live.com"
    "http://msn.com"
    "http://wordpress.com"
    |]

let print s = 
    // careful, don't create a synchronization bottleneck by printing
    //printf "%s" s
    ()

let printSummary info fullTimeMs =
    Array.sortInPlaceBy (fun (i,_,_) -> i) info
//  for i, size, time in info do
//      printfn "%2d  %7d  %5d" i size time
    let longest = info |> Array.map (fun (_,_,time) -> time) |> Array.max
    printfn "longest request took %dms" longest
    let bytes = info |> Array.sumBy (fun (_,size,_) -> float size)
    let seconds = float fullTimeMs / 1000.
    printfn "sucked down %7.2f KB/s" (bytes / 1024.0 / seconds)

let FetchAllSync() =
    let allsw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    let info = sites |> Array.mapi (fun i url ->
        let sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
        print "S"
        let req = WebRequest.Create(url) 
        use resp = req.GetResponse()
        use stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
        use reader = new StreamReader(stream,
                            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true, 4096) 
        print "-"
        let contents = reader.ReadToEnd()
        print "r"
        i, contents.Length, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    let time = allsw.ElapsedMilliseconds 
    printSummary info time
    time, info |> Array.sumBy (fun (_,size,_) -> size)

let FetchAllAsync() =
    let allsw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    let info = sites |> Array.mapi (fun i url -> async {
        let sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
        print "S"
        let req = WebRequest.Create(url) 
        use! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse()
        use stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
        use reader = new AsyncStreamReader(stream, // F# PowerPack
                           System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true, 4096) 
        print "-"
        let! contents = reader.ReadToEnd()  // in F# PowerPack
        print "r"
        return i, contents.Length, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds })
                    |> Async.Parallel 
                    |> Async.RunSynchronously 
    let time = allsw.ElapsedMilliseconds 
    printSummary info time
    time, info |> Array.sumBy (fun (_,size,_) -> size)

// By default, I think .NET limits you to 2 open connections at once
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit <- sites.Length 

for i in 1..3 do // to warmup and show variance
    let time1,r1 = FetchAllSync()
    printfn "Sync took %dms, result was %d" time1 r1
    let time2,r2 = FetchAllAsync()
    printfn "Async took %dms, result was %d  (speedup=%2.2f)" 
        time2 r2 (float time1/ float time2)
    printfn ""
```

On my 4-core box, this consistently gives a nearly 4x speedup.

EDIT

In reply to your comment, I've updated the code.  You're right in that I've added more sites and am not seeing the expected speedup (still holding steady around 4x).  I've started adding a little debugging output above, will continue investigating to see if something else is throttling the connections...

EDIT

Editted the code again.  Well, I found what might be the bottleneck.  Here's the implementation of AsyncReadToEnd in the PowerPack:

```
type System.IO.StreamReader with
   member s.AsyncReadToEnd () = 
       FileExtensions.UnblockViaNewThread (fun () -> s.ReadToEnd())
```

In other words, it just blocks a threadpool thread and reads synchronously.  Argh!!!  Let me see if I can work around that.

EDIT

Ok, the AsyncStreamReader in the PowerPack does the right thing, and I'm using that now.

However, the key issue seems to be *variance*.

When you hit, say, cnn.com, a lot of the time the result will come back in like 500ms.  But every once in a while you get that one request that takes 4s, and this of course potentially kills the apparent async perf, since the overall time is the time of the unluckiest request.

Running the program above, I see speedups from about 2.5x to 9x on my 2-core box at home.  It is very highly variable, though.  It's still possible there's some bottleneck in the program that I've missed, but I think the variance-of-the-web may account for all of what I'm seeing at this point.

Comment: I use fairly similar code.  As a sanity-check, i added a "do! Async,Sleep 1000" in a strategic place.  I have two of the four HTs disabled, and get a 4-fold speedup with 4 page requests And with 20 requests.  What does that tell ya?  It's getting late here, I'll try your DefaultConnectionLimit trick tomorrow.

Comment: I added some sample code that avoids web access APIs entirely as a proof of concept.  As you said, Async.Parallel seems to be the right fit here.

Comment: For tomorrow, will have a look at the web access APIs hitting localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Reactive Extensions for .NET combined with F#, you can write a very elegant solution - check out the sample at http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/11/16/making-async-io-work-for-you-reactive-style/ (this uses C#, but using F# is easy too; the key is using the Begin/End methods instead of the sync method, which even if you can make it compile, it will block up `n` ThreadPool threads unnecessarily, instead of the Threadpool just picking up completion routines as they come in)

Comment: I am specifically interested in creating a point of synchronization at the end of all async requests, so I can tally up the results.  I am also not sure about your comment on blocking the thread pool.

Comment: Observable.SelectMany will do the aggregation of all the async requests. Think about it - if you use the sync methods of HttpWebRequest, how could it not block the thread pool? Some thread somewhere is sitting waiting on the HttpWebResponse, unless you're using the Begin/End async methods.

Comment: This does not block anything: type System.Net.WebRequest with
   member request.ReadResponseAsync = 
      async {
         use! response = request.AsyncGetResponse()
         use responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()
         use reader = new StreamReader(responseStream)
         return reader.ReadToEnd()
      }

Comment: ReadToEnd has to block, it returns the entire stream as a string. How can it not block? It's entirely possible that F# does something tricky in the background, but by default, ReadToEnd is definitely a blocking call

Comment: Boy, that comment looks ugly, sorry about formatting...  I am not down-voting anyone, promise.

Comment: It's the F# magic that got C# people thinking.  Trust me, it does not block, because of composition of async blocks.

Comment: @GregC No, you might be right, F# has magic async workflow powers - in general though, when you call sync methods, you have to block up a threadpool thread

Comment: `ReadToEnd` definitely does block.  You want `AsyncReadToEnd` (from the PowerPack) to avoid blocking there.

Answer (score 2):

My bet is that the speedup you're experiencing is not significant enough for your taste because you're either using a subtype of WebRequest or a class relying on it (such as WebClient).
If that's the case, you need to set the [MaxConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.configuration.connectionmanagementelement.maxconnection.aspx) on the ConnectionManagementElement (and I suggest you only set it if needed otherwise it's gonna become a pretty time-consuming operation) to a high value, depending on the number of simultaneous connections you wanna initiate from your application.

Comment: See also the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an F# guy, but from a pure .NET perspective what you're looking for is TaskFactory::FromAsync where the asynchronous call you'd be wrapping in a Task would be something like HttpRequest::BeginGetResponse. You could also wrap up the EAP model that WebClient exposes using a TaskCompletionSource. More on both of these [topics here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997405.aspx) on MSDN.

Hopefully with this knowledge you can find the nearest native F# approach to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321473.aspx) is a familiar entity.  However, F#'s promise is that it hides continuation-passing style, making the actual algorithm stand out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that avoids the unknowns, such as web access latency.  I am getting under 5% CPU utilization, and about 60-80% efficiency for both sync and async code paths.

```
open System.Diagnostics

let numWorkers = 200
let asyncDelay = 50

let main =
   let codeBlocks = [for i in 1..numWorkers -> 
                        async { do! Async.Sleep asyncDelay } ]

   while true do
      printfn "Concurrent started..."
      let sw = new Stopwatch()
      sw.Start()
      codeBlocks |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
      sw.Stop()
      printfn "Concurrent in %d millisec" sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
      printfn "efficiency: %d%%" (int64 (asyncDelay * 100) / sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)

      printfn "Synchronous started..."
      let sw = new Stopwatch()
      sw.Start()
      for codeBlock in codeBlocks do codeBlock |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
      sw.Stop()
      printfn "Synchronous in %d millisec" sw.ElapsedMilliseconds
      printfn "efficiency: %d%%" (int64 (asyncDelay * numWorkers * 100) / sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)

main
```